# Error when copying public key

Tags: xubuntu, ssh, keys

I have created a key pair in Xubuntu 15. I want to copy the public key to a Windows 10 laptop in order to allow ssh connection only from there, but when I run (as root):

```
  ssh-copy-id myuser@my.ip.x.x
```

it returns after a while:

```
  /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed

  /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: ssh: connect to host my.ip.x.x port 22: Connection timed out
```

I have the windows firewall open for port 22, and allowed ssh_key application to communicate through the firewall. In Ubuntu I have ufw allowing all outgoing communications.

The laptop is not connected to the local network, is that a problem?

Comment: _“The laptop is not connected to the local network, is that a problem?”_ So how it _is_ connected?

Comment: It is connected to Internet

Answer (score 2):

You say in your question that you have ufw allowing all outgoing connections. Adding a key would be an incoming connection in my mind. Run the following command on your server to open port 22 for incoming.

```
Sudo ufw allow 22
```

Then restart ssh

```
Sudo service ssh restart
```

And try to import your key again. Also you may want to consider moving ssh to an alternative port.

Log in to your router and make sure you have port 22 forwarded to the correct internal ip. Also if you are connecting externally, verify that your ISP is not assigning you dynamic ip address'. Otherwise the address will be consistently changing and you will then need to use a service such as dyndns.

Answer (score 0):

`ssh-copy-id` wants to communicate with a SSH server (`sshd` on Linux). The SSH server listens to port 22. Ensure that you have an SSH server running on the target (Windows) system, and check its logs.